# A little bit confused about the solution for 2016 AIME II #7

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Squares $ABCD$ and $EFGH$ have a common center at $\overline{AB} || \overline{EF}$. The area of $ABCD$ is 2016, and the area of $EFGH$ is a smaller positive integer. Square $IJKL$ is constructed so that each of its vertices lies on a side of $ABCD$ and each vertex of $EFGH$ lies on a side of $IJKL$. Find the difference between the largest and smallest positive integer values for the area of $IJKL$.

Solution states that since $EFGH||ABCD$, the angles that each square cuts another are equal, so all the triangles are formed by a vertex of a larger square and $2$ adjacent vertices of a smaller square are similar. Therefore, the areas form a geometric progression, so since $2016=12^{2} \cdot 14$, we have the maximum area is $2016 \cdot \dfrac{11}{12} = 1848$.

Here is where I'm confused, where did this $\dfrac{11}{12}$ com from? I get that since $2016$ contains $12^2$ 12 has to do with the geometric progresssion mentioned above but what exactly doesit stand for?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the area of $EFGH$ and $s$ be the area of $IJKL$. As $n$, $s$ and $2016$ form a geometric progression, we have: 
$$s=\sqrt{2016n}=12\sqrt{14n}.$$

For $s$ to be integer we must choose $n=14k^2$, where $k$ is an integer. But $n<2016$, that is $n<14\cdot12^2$, so the largest admissible choice for $k$ is $k=11$ and $s_{MAX}=12\cdot14\cdot11$.